# Apache stuck on preparing to delegate

Tags: apache

I have this problem: apache tomcat 8 stuck on preparing launch delegate. my problem is not about timeout, I set start in 450 seconds and stop in 150 seconds

Answer (score -1):

i got same problem. but i solve.
i used jdk1.8 and tomcat v8.5, and closed network.

when i set 'ajp/1.3' in server.xml, i got same problem.

soultion is

this project -> run as -> run configrations -> arguments TAB
write -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

try this.

Answer (score -1):

sorry, today i got this problem again.
i thought solved this problem but i wrong.

but i just know onething,

subject project (right click)-> run as -> run configrations -> select apache Tomcat (left tree) -> click run button (right bottom)

if you run like this. you can see works successful.

i dont know what difference run configrations run button and run server button of server tab....